# Problems knit rmarkdown when size file html output is over 5 MB

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, knitr, flexdashboard

When I knit a flexdashboard file to html have a problem when my output file exceeds 5 MB. I generate the HTML but nothing is seen. When I try smaller files I have no problem.

"C:/Users/dconde/AppData/Local/Pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS INFORME.utf8.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output INFORME.html --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template "C:\Users\dconde\Documents\R\R-3.6.2\library\flexdashboard\rmarkdown\templates\flex_dashboard\resources\default.html" --variable "theme:cosmo" --include-in-header "C:\Users\dconde\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWYSzMM\rmarkdown-str34545475e76.html" --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" --lua-filter "C:/Users/dconde/Documents/R/R-3.6.2/library/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:/Users/dconde/Documents/R/R-3.6.2/library/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/latex-div.lua" --include-in-header "C:\Users\dconde\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWYSzMM\file345422c33b31html" --highlight-style pygments --include-before-body "C:\Users\dconde\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWYSzMM\file34547f4a6ea.html" --include-after-body "C:\Users\dconde\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWYSzMM\file34543c7575f.html" --css style.css

Somebody can help me?

Comment: Can you include the actual error message in addition to the program called? Can you provide a [mre], possibly using some random data?

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't give me any error message. It generates the html file but not completely, it only reaches up to 5 Mb. I think it is an insufficient memory problem. When I add the YAML self_contained: false
    lib_dir: libs
the problem is solved. Thanks @Ralf Stubner.